# MVC model view controller in jsp

Tags: model-view-controller

Im new to jsp and MVC. Im studying this application that registers a customer into the database and then searches for it. The files that Im creating are Customer.java, Customer.jsp, CustomerDAO.java, CustomerContrtoller.java, CustomerService.java, result.jsp and ConnectionManager.java. How does this follow the MVC model? How do I know what is the model, view and controller in this app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MVC applies as follows to Jsps:

The **model** is your Customer.java. This model is used by the Jsp to render Html. The Jsp is the **view**. The CustomerController is the **controller**. The controller handles actions, like clicks, of the user, prepares the model and sends it to the Jsp.

Your confusion comes from the CustomerDao, I think. You have to understand that MVC is a frontend pattern. The model used in MVC **can** be the same as the Dao from the database, but most of the time it's not. Just the interaction between the Jsp, the controller and the model displayed on the Jsp is part of the MVC concept.